# Money bag reported missing while manager was out of town. Now he is being asked to repay almost $1,000.00. Legal?

Tags: management

I am a store manger at a local Hauling rental. While I was out of town, an employee called me to report missing money bag. (Video footage shows an employee counting $ and placing it in bank deposit bag.) When I returned to work, I searched for money bag to no avail. Checked with bank; bag not accounted for. Spoke with superior re: situation. He did not call police nor did I. I depended on superior to take the lead. Now I am being "volunteered" to repay money. Legal? What recourse do I have?  I do not want to lose my job! This occurred in large Texas city about a week ago!

Comment: Any particular reason for not calling the police? It seems the obvious thing to do to create a record of what happened.

Comment: This is going to depend on location, but I think it's fairly universal that employees can't be penalized for loss if they weren't directly responsible for causing it (and even then they may not be liable).

Comment: Might be a better fit on law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Stickler for details in The Netherlands here, so no clue about US/Texas laws. However: you're missing company property: get cops involved. Make sure your superiors' superior gets notified of you involving cops (after you've involved cops). Who knows: "might've been that superior"...

Comment: Were you involved in the disappearance of the money?

Comment: Is there some reason the title says "he is" rather than "I am"?

Comment: Wouldn't paying some money seem to imply that either you are complicit in the crime or somewhat guilty?

Comment: What does the video show happened to the bank deposit bag after the employee had filled it? If that is not on video, then why not? What does the employee who filled the bag say happened?

Answer (score 23):

> Legal?

Definitely not legal, **unless** you signed something saying your responsible for what happens when you are not present.  Refuse to pay for this, in writing or via email.  You probably should contact an attorney too.

Call the police ASAP and report what happened.  Show them the video and have the supervisor file an insurance claim.  Surely the company has theft **insurance**.  Also if you can, provide evidence to the police of where **you** were when the theft occurred.

Answer (score 8):

> Now I am being "volunteered" to repay money. Legal? What recourse do I
>   have? I do not want to lose my job!

Local laws differ. And the only real ways to know if it is legal or not would be to talk with a lawyer, or let it go through the court system.

I can't imagine how it could be legal to make you responsible for lost money without charging you with the theft. One recourse would be to tell your employer that you have no intention of paying back any money since you didn't take it and that you would see them in court.

Of course, you may lose your job. Texas is an at will employment state. That means they can dismiss you for this, for any other reason, or for no reason at all. If they go to this extreme, I suspect they will fire you anyway - even if you do pay the money back.

Time to start looking for a new job.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not a lawyer and I can’t advise on what is legal. What I will talk about is what is probable and practical when an employer and employee are in such a situation.

If you are just an employee (i.e. not a franchisee or some other sort of business panther) then they can’t make you pay the money. The can ask you to pay it and you can decide if you want to pay them. If they make paying the money a condition of keeping you job that may amount to unfair dismissal in some jurisdictions. However, in an *at will state* in the United States its very unlikely you will get any satisfaction in making that argument.

You shouldn’t pay them the money. As the store manager you own them a duty to take reasonable steps to ensure money is not stolen. Then probably believe you didn’t do this and that is why they asked you to pay them. However, employers should face the cost of their employees mistakes. If you purchased merchandise which you couldn’t sell at a profit, they shouldn’t ask them to make up the difference. The principle is the same. However, they can let you go if they think your poor performance lead them to lose money.

What you should do is demonstrate to them that you are taking steps that this won’t happen again. Figuring out what happened to the money would make this easier. It could also help if you recover the money. It is odd that you haven’t involved the police, although they may may be attempting to gurard their reputation in some way. Even if you don’t know how the money disappeared show them what steps you are taking to keep their money safe in the future.